# how does window resizing work in jquery?

Tags: jquery

So I have this function, it's quite long and complicated.

Now I can get it working if the window width changes, but the scroll event needs to fire first.

How do I get it to work on the resize of the window?

```
       $(document).bind("scroll.myScroll", function () {

    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        masthead = $(".mast-head").outerHeight();
        notef = $(".note-f").outerHeight();
        frontcontainheight = $(".center").outerHeight();
        //derivative variable
            abpos = (frontcontainheight / 2.1);

        sidebarwidth = $(".sidebarholder").width();
        dataheight = $(".data-top").outerHeight(true);

        controlwidth = $(".loop-contain").outerWidth();
        innerwidth = $(".front-contain").outerWidth();
        //get side-contain width dynamically    
        //derivative variable   
            sidecon = (controlwidth - innerwidth);

        elem = $(".center");
        paddingTopBottom = elem.innerHeight() - elem.height();


        console.log (controlwidth);

            if ($(window).width() > 1200) {
                if (scrollTop > notef + dataheight + masthead - 50 + paddingTopBottom) {
                    $('.side-contain').css({
                        position: "fixed",
                        left: sidebarwidth + innerwidth,
                        top: "50px",
                        width: sidecon - "24"

                    });

                }
                if (scrollTop < notef + dataheight + masthead - 50 + paddingTopBottom) {
                    $('.side-contain').css({
                    position: "relative",
                    left: "",
                    top: "",
                    width: ""
                    });

                }
                if (scrollTop > abpos + masthead - 50 + paddingTopBottom) {
                    $('.side-contain').css({
                    position: "absolute",
                    left: innerwidth,
                    top: abpos - notef, // if the scroll is more than half the height of front-contain then lock to that position, ie. the amount scroll of front-contain - 63px.

                    width: sidecon - "24"

                    });

                }


            } else if ($(window).width() < 1200) {
                  $('.side-contain').css({
                    position: "relative",
                    left: "",
                    top: "",
                    width: ""
                    });

            }


});
```

Comment: offtopic: you can pass all of your css attributes at the same time, no need to make 4 separate selector and `.css()` calls..

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just find it easier to write that way before I actually finalise anything. I know it's bad.

Comment: Has anyone got any input on this? I can't see why $(window).resize wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
 $(window).on("resize", function () {
      $.trigger('scroll.myScroll');
  }).trigger("resize");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using a responsive grid rather than the resize event if possible.  @media queries and selective styles are the way to go.  http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do here but every time you check the scroll positions etc you're forcing the ui thread to re-evaluate positioning.  This is expensive. If you need to have something scroll at a certain height then at least make sure you put the scroll depth check on a timeout so that you're not locking the UI thread.  Right now for every pixel change on resize you're checking all sorts of heights and whatnot.  Put a little delay in there (at least 15ms) to let the UI thread breathe while you batter it with "where is this element, where is that element?!?!?!"

Additionally you're hitting .css multiple times.  Why not put those changes into an object?
.css({ "background-color": "#ffe", "border-left": "5px solid #ccc" }).  http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties

Aside from that the "resize" event should do it for you... see above

Comment: Well what it's doing is locking a sidebar to the top of the screen when a certain amount of the page is scrolled, hence all the variables. It then gets the width of a few elements to decide where to put that sidebar (it's on the right of the page), after more scrolling it sets it position:absolute so the lower part can be seen. Site is already 'responsive' with media queries, this is something that can only be done with javascript. Updated with new code so it's not hitting .css so much.

Comment: Can you do an @media query to apply position absolute or fixed at different resolutions?  In any case try adding a border on resize completely outside of the code you have here.  Start with the base case.  Then you can try to get other things to happen on resize